# How polymorphism works in Java

Tags: java

Can someone explain me whether same name methods are override when we extend?

ClassA ab = new ClassB?

Which methods does ab sees?

**Class A:**

```
public class ClassA {

    public static int count = 0;

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Print A");
    }

    public static void printNumber() {
        System.out.println("Class A " + (++count));
    }
}
```

**Class B:**
In class B which methods will be overrided?

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    public static int count=0;

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Class B");
    }

    public static void printNumber() {
        System.out.println("Class B " + (++count));
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**
Which method will be called here?

```
public class ClassTest {

    public static void main(String [] arg) {

        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        ClassA ab = new ClassB();

        a.print();
        a.printNumber();

        b.print();
        b.printNumber();

        ab.print();  //Why when we call print() method returns print method of ClassA
        ab.printNumber()    ;// Why when we call printNumber() method return method of ClassB
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `ClassC`? This code would not complie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a static method depends on the declaring type rather than the instantiated type.

So in this line:

```
ClassA ab = new ClassB();
  ^               ^
declared type    instantiated type
```

ab will always use static methods of it's declared type (`Class A`) -- in the case of `printNumber();` your IDE should actually give you a suggestion along the lines of:

> Static member ClassA.printNumber() accessed via instance reference

and will probably suggest adjusting the line to:

```
ClassA.printNumber();
```

This differs from calling a dynamic method (like `print()`) which will always attempt to call the overriden method of the instantiated type (in the case of ab the instantiated type is `ClassB`)